# How to retrieve an average from a specific data type from a column in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table called products, which contains two rows (plus others):price and mfr.  How would I list the average price for items provided by a particular manufacturer (using a summary query)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage FROM Products WHERE mfr = 'particularManufacter'
```

but for future I recommend do your homework by yourself. But I was student too :)

Comment: I think it's not correct because the result is just for one mfr. As I mentioned, the best way to do is to make use of GROUP BY.

Comment: yes, you're right. I read it quickly and I don't realize that @unit want to list all prices. I thought that he wanted to know average price for particular manufacter.

Answer (score 4):

Check out aggregate functions (group by): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html (this is from the mysql manual, which is a flavor of SQL. change if needed something else)

It has amongst other an "average" function :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
SELECT mfr, AVG(price) FROM Products Group By mfr
```

The AVG function will return the average price for each group.